# How to sort by multiple columns using spring jdbctemplate?

Tags: sql-server, spring, sorting, sql-order-by, jdbctemplate

Say I have a sql query where I want to sort by different columns. However I want to do that separately.

For example, when user wants to sort only by firstName, I want to run

```
Select .... from table order by firstName
```

when user wants to sort only by lastName, I want to run

```
Select .... from table order by lastName
```

and so on. I have about 100 `columns` and I don't want to create 100 `sql files` and pass the strings to `queryForList` method of `jdbcTemplate`. So is there an efficient way to doing it? If I have an enum for all 100 columns which exactly match the name of the real column in database, can I somehow pass this string as the element by which I want to order by?

I tried using namedParameterJdbcTemplate by doing something like

```
Select .... from table order by :query
```

and in my java code, I did

```
// njdbc stands for namedParameterJdbcTemplate
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("query","firstName");
njdbc.queryForList(sql, params);
```

But its giving me a bind error since I am not binding on a value but on real sql syntax.

Another way I thought of doing was to actually use simple java String operations(like replace method) to replace that `:query` with my column name(firstName for instance). However this is not the right way to do it since this is prone to sql injections.

Note: Removed a lot of sql syntax for brevity. I am also using sql-server in case it helps. However I think a solution for this would be database agnostic.

Comment: With Bind variable in JDBCTemplate it will not work. You need to use JPA based query. Follow this link https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-six-sorting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in noting that sql injection is a potential problem, but you can guard against that by checking the input.

You could potentially use something like this:

```
@Value("${some-property}")
private List<String> validSortColumns;

public void foo(String sortColumn) {
    String newSql = sql;
    if (validSortColumns.contains(sortColumn))
       newSql = sql + " ORDER BY " + sortColumn;

    return njdbc.queryForList(newSql);
}
```

As you are already using spring I would certainly recommend putting the list of valid column names into configuration to make them easier to manage.